ResultSet.getObject(int columnIndex) hit "Invalid Column Type" SQLException for DATE column of OracleSQL DB
JDK: temurin-jdk8u412-b08
Springboot: 2.7.18
When I use Spring JdbcTemplate.update(final PreparedStatementCreator psc, final KeyHolder generatedKeyHolder), found out that
ResultSet.getObject(int columnIndex) hit "Invalid Column Type" SQLException for DATE column of OracleSQL DB

I have upgraded spring boot version, but same error happens
updated SQL query and parameters from Java:
insert into SAMPLE_TBL (ID, A_COL, B_COL, C_DATE) values (?,?,?,?) RETURNING (ID, C_DATE)
params:
1234
1234
1234
"2024-08-05T01:22:16.229"

Does the exception have an outer exception that includes the SQL? Either way, can you include the SQL that causes the error, together with any parameters supplied, into the question. That way, readers can check whether there is any inconsistency.

updated SQL query and parameters

how is the C_DATE field var decorated? as it is its only a String

I use preparedStatement, and just use setMethod() to set it
ps.setTimestamp(i, Timestamp.valueOf((LocalDateTime) cDate));
